# How to remove extra quotes from strings in a set?

Tags: python

I am working on a method and trying to return a list in the format `List[Tuple[Set[str], Set[str]]]` but I can't figure out how to remove extra quotes. self._history[dates[dat]]._ridings is a list of strings.
what this method does is check the voting areas in a election then comparing those areas with next election or previous election to see which areas were in first but not in second and which were in second but not in first and those are the two elements of tuple. there could be more than one area which may or may not be present in this election. self._history[dates[dat]]._ridings is a list with certain areas in a election and i add 1 to dat so it compares with the next election so every election is compared with the previous one.

I have tried using split and replace methods but doesn't seems to be working since it is a set not string

```
list1 = []
    dates = list(self._history)
    for dat in range(0, len(dates) - 1):
        a = set(self._history[dates[dat]]._ridings)
        b = set(self._history[dates[dat + 1]]._ridings)
        list1.append(tuple([(a-b), (b-a)]))
    return list1
```

Expected : `[({"St. Paul's...St. Paul's"})]`
Actual   : `[({'"St. Paul.... Paul\'s"'})]`

Comment: Could you show us what values are in the initial list? Your Expected and Actual strings are also a bit weird: At least one is missing a "St."? And are you really handling the same value multiple times? Are you sure your strings do not contain quotes themselves?

Comment: self._history[dates[dat]]._ridings would be a list with [ 'st. paul's', "Toronto center"]

Comment: why is one string in the list `[ 'st. paul's', "Toronto center"]` comes with `'` and the other with `"` around them? is that the actual result from `self._history[dates[dat]]._ridings`?

Comment: sorry they both have "

Comment: When you print `self._history[dates[dat]]._ridings`, can you confirm that they don't have quotes?

Comment: is it possible for you to provide some examples of the strings so we can reproduce it? i just tried to reproduce it but in my IDE, it did not have the extra quote on it

Comment: i tried this `sample_list = ['st. paul\'s', 'Toronto center', 'San Fransisco']` and `sample_list_2 = ['st. paul\'s', 'Toronto center', 'New York']`. then i put them in a set `a = set(sample_list)` and `b = set(sample_list_2)`. then i do this `tuple([(a-b), (b-a)])`, my result is `({'San Fransisco'}, {'New York'})` - no extra quotes

Comment: ["St. Paul's", "Toronto--St. Paul's"] here is a list

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring function to remove the character at index 0 and the character at index (string length - 1)

Comment: It's not necessary that the set will have only one string...It could have many

Comment: Your example doesn’t show that. Please provide an example of an expanded set.